# Unable to configure the PyDev interpreter in Eclipse

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse, pydev, python-3.7

We have the newest version of Eclipse IDE, and specifically the Java EE Developer package. We also have 64-bit Python 3.7 installed at-

```
C:\Program Files\Python37
```

I can install PyDev and continue like so

```
Windows--> Prefrences--> PyDev-->Interpeters-->Python Interpeters-->New
```

But when I name the Interpeter and select our Python.exe file at C:\Program Files\Python37 I get the following error-

```
See error log for details.
Can't find relative path:pysrc/interpreterInfo.py 
within:org.python.pydev.core_6.5.0.201809011628 [1001]
```

[Snip of the error code and resulting window for new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnen6.png)

If I attempt to add an interpreter using either the Advanced Auto-Config or Quick Auto-Config buttons I get the following error for both options-

```
Errors getting info on discovered interpreter(s).
See error log for details.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find relative 
path:pysrc/interpreterInfo.py within:org.python.pydev.core_6.5.0.201809011628 [1001]
```

[Snip of error code and resulting window for auto-configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df22c.png)

I have tried reinstalling Python in several locations but haven't had any luck. Thanks for reading any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: That's strange... first time I see this error (seems like somehow your install became corrupted).

Can you check if that file is available there?

i.e.: do you have the file interpreterInfo.py in the folder: eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.5.0.201809011628/pysrc?

Comment: Well I checked to see if `interpreterInfo.py` was in that location and it was not. I copied it from another instillation of Eclipse on a different PC and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great that it works, albeit it's strange that your installation became corrupted...